# Different value for 'get/setDestination' Directory

Tags: android, android-download-manager

**Tested in Emulator**

At first I make a directory in this form :

```
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "SubFolderName");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
```

That make directory in this path : `/storage/emulated/0/SubFolderName`

Now, I need to use this path for downloaded file, so add this code:

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "SubFolderName","FileName");
```

That return this path: `/storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/SubFolderName/`

Too try before this:

```
 request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity(), root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "SubFolderName","FileName");
```

This section are repeated : `storage/emulated/0`

I check my codes but there-are not mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying which directory in external storage.

There are several directories you can use depending on what you are storing e.g "Downloads", "Video"

You can use the downloads directory like this for example:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + "SubFolderName/" + mTedListModel.get(position).getTitle()).mkdirs();
```

And then set your destination with the request manager as

```
  .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, + "SubFolderName/" + mTedListModel.get(position).getTitle());
```

Comment: i use in this form and was right : request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("SubFolderName","FileName"); - without `Environment.DIRECTORY_....`

Answer (score 0):

You are using setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(), as i can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) it is already adding the external root dir so you only need to especify the directory type,subpath and file name.

Example:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,"SubFolderName/FileName");
```

Hope im not wrong.